# How to use context.Context with cancellation in chain of function calls

Tags: go

Suppose I have these functions:

```
func A(ctx context.Context) {
    // A takes some time to process
}

func B(ctx context.Context) {
    // B takes some time to process
}

func C(ctx context.Context) {
    // C takes some time to process
}
```

**Note: Every function call takes some time to process.**

**Note: B should be called inside function A & C should be called inside function B.**

Just need an example for this specific situation.

Comment: Exactly the same as if they don't take time to process. What specifically about it are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I searched and I could not find an example for this situation when chain of function calls happen.

Comment: The chain also doesn't make any difference. Again, what specifically are you having trouble with, and what have you tried?

Comment: I am just trying to write a program with cancellation so whenever i want, i can cancel the whole process of function calls. And I just need an example for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You just pass the same context as the argument, but whenever you wait for results from channel\remote server\anything you use select statement with waiting for the <- ctx.Done(). Whenever the context would be canceled (by cancel function or due to the timeout), the internal chan would be closed and the receive operation always unblocks on the closed channel.

The general post about cancelation (without context, but mentally replace doneCh with ctx.Done())
https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

Talk about cancelation (the context example from page 15)
https://talks.golang.org/2014/gotham-context.slide#15

Couple of examples 
https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/golang/2018-06-17-golang-using-context-cancellation/